# Wait until the supervisor is ready before execute the test

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I have written a test for my actors as follows:

```
class DetectorSpec extends BddSpec {

    private val sap = new SapMock()
        .withExposedPorts(8080)
        .waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/"))

    private val kafka = new KafkaContainer("5.2.1")


    sap.start()
    kafka.start()


    override def afterAll(): Unit = {
        sap.stop()
        kafka.stop()
    }

    private def withKafkaOfflineSapOnline(testCode: TestProbe[ServerEvent] => Unit)
    : Unit = {

        val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
        s"""
            kafka {
                servers = "127.0.0.1:9092"
            }
            sap {
                server = "ws://${sap.getContainerIpAddress}:${sap.getMappedPort(8080)}"
            }""")

        val testKit = ActorTestKit("testSystem1", config)
        val inbox = testKit.createTestProbe[ServerEvent]("Receiver")
        testKit.spawn(DetectorSupervisor.create(), "DetectorSupervisor")
        testKit.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(ServerStateKey, inbox.ref)

        Thread.sleep(4000)

        testCode(inbox)
        testKit.shutdownTestKit()
    }


    feature("Detect Kafka and SAP availability") {
        scenario("SAP is online and Kafka is offline") {
        withKafkaOfflineSapOnline { inbox =>
                Given("I am waiting for the current state message")
                When("I am receive the state message")
                val msg = inbox.receiveMessage(3.second)
                Then("it should contain `Kafka is offline`")
                msg should be(ServerOnlineApproved)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see in the fixture method `withKafkaOfflineSapOnline`, there is a statement `Thread.sleep(4000)` to make it sure,
that actor `DetectorSupervisor` with they children is ready before the test get started.

Is there a better way to do it?

Without the `Thread.sleep(4000)` statement, it seems to be, that the actors are not ready, when the test is starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your actor only communicates with mocks that you control directly and you do not need real concurrency in your test, you can use the `CallingThreadDispatcherConfigurator`. This makes sense when you write a unit test for a single actor or you want to make actor interaction deterministic in tests.

All asynchronous code will be run on the test thread. So when you send a message to an actor you can usually be sure it is processed before the next statement of your test.

Here is an example of how to create a test kit for this purpose:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(
s"""akka.actor.default-dispatcher = {
   |  type = akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcherConfigurator
   |}
   |akka.actor.testkit.typed.single-expect-default = 0s
""".stripMargin
)

val testKit = ActorTestKit(ActorTestKitBase.testNameFromCallStack(), config)
```